# Hw question from book in the Row space and rank-nullity theorem section

Tags: linear-algebra

A is a $4 \times 5$, rank 2, matrix for which the vectors $x_{1} = (17, 6, -13, 1, 2)^T$, $x_{2} = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)^T$, and $x_{3} = (5, 4, 3, 2, 1)^T$ all satisfy $Ax=0$. Prove that $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ span the solution space to the system $Ax=0$.

I really don't have any idea where to start and the textbook this problem comes from is supremely unhelpful...

Comment: What is the title and author of the book?

Comment: Linear Algebra: Ideas and Applications by Richard Penney

Answer (score 1):

Since $rank(M) = 2$, for $M$ as your matrix (looking at the row-space), we know there are two linearly independent row vectors. This means we have a nullity of $3$ for the row-space of the matrix, as the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ is $5$. The nullity is the cardinality of the kernel (also called the null-space), which $Ker(M) = \{ x : x \in \mathbb{R}^{5} \land Ax = 0 \}$.

So if we have three linearly independent vectors that all provide solutions, what can we say about the kernel? Are we spanning? Do we have a basis?